# Возможно ли и как сверстать такой фон?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, css3

Как сверстать такой фон для странички, чтобы она корректно отображалась на всех разрешениях экрана? Чтобы кликабельные элементы, в частности круг, не разъезжались. И его границы цета совпадали с границами фона
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мэрия пишется через "э".

Comment: В чем именно возникло затруднение? Покажите проблему

Comment: Krom, спасибо за замечание. tutankhamun, описание есть в самом вопросе - круг не попадает по центру

Comment: У вас кстати и дизайн не особо "совпадает". По вопросу – делайте логотип в фоне, а кликабельные элементы ссылками и будет вам счастье

Comment: Krom Stern, круто набирать рейтинг лайками за комментарии, не относящиеся к сути вопроса )))

Comment: @Chekist: оценки комментариев не приносят репутации (рейтинга, кармы).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно сделать несколько наборов графики под разные разрешения, и использовать наиболее подходящий через [`@media`](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119127/). Круг пусть будет просто частью фона. Фон выравнивать по верху и середине. И поверх круга/лого разместить прозрачную кликабельную область.

Ещё можно скриптом генерить этот несложный рисунок кривыми Безье – в svg. И даже сделать какую-то анимацию этих волн )

Comment: Фон делать надо какого размера? Максимально возможного разрешения экрана?

Comment: фон в таком варианте – да, максимально возможного. Ну, или сделайте ему края размыто уходящими в прозрачность или какой-то сплошной цвет. Варианты разрешений можете [взять у Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries): Phones (<768px), Tablets (≥768px), Desktops (≥992px), Desktops (≥1200px).

Answer (score 5):

Может из этого что-то выйдет выжать:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url('http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/70000/velka/wooden-floor-with-green-background.jpg') center center fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.content {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: url('http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/70000/velka/wooden-floor-with-green-background.jpg') center center fixed no-repeat;
  background-size: 100vw ;
  -webkit-filter: contrast(150%);
  filter: contrast(150%);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
   
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

https://jsfiddle.net/6oqo7sqc/ - делаете фон через RGBA и выставляете нужный уровень прозрачности.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: url('http://www.zastavki.com/pictures/originals/2012/Backgrounds_Rainbow_spectrum_035587_.jpg') center center;
   background-size: 100%;
}

.content {
  border-radius: 80px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center
}
```

Comment: тут сложность в том, что под кругом цвета не темнее, а темнее и насыщеннее. Полупрозрачным наложением такого эффекта не добиться. А рисовать непрозрачный круг – есть риск ошибиться на 1px с позиционированием.

Comment: Можно попробовать через css3 фильтры, но этот способ жутко не кроссбраузерный. Например, как тут - http://jsfiddle.net/peterbenoit/EppdS/, только blur поменять на contrast.

Comment: контраст сделает тёмное темнее, а светлое светлее. Насыщенность он не повысит.